# store and retrieve numbers in android with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store and retrieve numbers in android so later I can do calculations on the results. I am managing to store and get strings but for some reason can't seem to get it to work for integers

here is the string code I tested

save...

```
getSharedPreferences("words", 0).edit().putString("YAS", wordString).commit();
```

receive...

```
String words= getSharedPreferences("words", 0).getString("YAS", "");
t.setText(words);
```

but when I try a similar thing with integers it doesn't work.

save...

```
getSharedPreferences("number", 0).edit().putInt("numbers", 1).commit();
```

receive...

```
int test2 = getSharedPreferences("number", 0).getInt("numbers",0);
```

Basically I need the saved variable to be 0 before the button is pressed (which I'm guessing it will be since it doesn't exist at that point) and then change to 1 when pressed. No matter how many times the button is pressed it will only ever equal 1
cheers for any help

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? A `ClassCastException` maybe?

Comment: so what problem you are facing your code is write

Comment: until I uncomment those two lines of codes in each activity, everything works fine. If I uncomment those and run the app it ends unexpectedly and I get the following error in my LogCat in Eclipse

06-13 12:06:06.913: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-13 12:06:06.913: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ikon.ik/ikon.ik.Icons}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Comment: Looks like you are using setText method over a TextView, and passing an Integer as a parameter instead of a String. If you set an Integer on that method, the system will think it is a system identifier rather than a literal value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From you comment I assume that you are doing something like this:

```
int test2 = getSharedPreferences("number", 0).getInt("numbers",0);
t.setText(test2);
```

This will make the system look for a ressource in your xml ressource files with ressource id with the value test2 (0 in your case). This ressource will not exist and you get an exception.

Use

```
int test2 = getSharedPreferences("number", 0).getInt("numbers",0);
t.setText(Integer.toString(test2));
```

instead.

Comment: @oscar I think this is answer to your question.

Comment: YESS!!! Thankyou!

It's fixed! I think I should be able to get the rest working now! cheers

Thanks to everyone else who also tried to help

Answer (score 0):

You wrong at that point that SharedPrefereces doesn't exist before button is pressed. At the first time - yes, it doesn't exists. But when you're saved your value it will be there, no matter how many times you restarted the application. However, if you delete your app then SharedPrefereces will be deleted too.

Looks like that you should use a simple integer variable (class field, for example).

Comment: yeah, sorry I meant the first time ever pressed not just on launch, obviously after that it will exist and should always be value 1, if done correctly how I want it to work :/

Comment: @oscar and what is your problem?

Comment: When I run the app it stops unexpectedly and gives me this error in my eclipse LogCat

06-13 12:06:06.913: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-13 12:06:06.913: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ikon.ik/ikon.ik.Icons}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0